# Finding pvalue, r and adjusted r^2 for SVR regression model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, non-linear-regression

I want to use Support Vector Regression (SVR) for regression as it seems quite powerful when I have several features. As I found a very-easy-to-use implementation in scikit-learn, I'm using that implementation. My questions below are regarding this python package in particular, but if you have any solution in any other language or package please let me know as well.

So, I'm using the following code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf')
scoring = ['neg_mean_absolute_error', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'r2']


scores = cross_validate(estimator, X, y, cv=KFold(10, shuffle=True), scoring=scoring, return_train_score=False)

score = -1 * scores['test_neg_mean_absolute_error']
print("MAE: %.4f (%.4f)" % (score.mean(), score.std()))

score = -1 * scores['test_neg_mean_squared_error']
print("MSE: %.4f (%.4f)" % (score.mean(), score.std()))

score = scores['test_r2']
print("R^2: %.4f (%.4f)" % (score.mean(), score.std()))
```

As you can see, I can easily use 10-fold cross validation by dividing my data in 10 shuffled folds, and getting all the MAE, MSE and r^2 for each fold very easily.

However, my big question is **how can I get the pvalue, r and adjusted r^2** for my SVR regression model specifically, just like I find in other python packages including *statsmodels* for linear regressions?

I guess I will have to implement the cross validation with KFold by myself in order to achieve this, but I don't think that's a big problem. The issue is that I'm not sure how to get these scores from sklearn's implementation of SVR itself.

Comment: As a p-value is related to a statistical test (specifically the probability that allows to reject the null hypothesis under a specific threshold), what do you want to test in your case?

Comment: @IgorOA I want to test exactly what you just said. When I do a linear regression in any other R package or even *statsmodel* python package, I always have the pvalue from the f statistics. For regressions, if that pvalue is below a certain threshold, that means that we can reject the null-hypothesis and conclude that the model provides a better fit than the intercept-only model. So, as SVR is also a regression model, I just want to have that value, as well as other common regression scores: adjusted r^2 and the r coefficient itself.

Comment: After the linear regression, one can test if the **coefficients** are equal to zero (Null hypothesis) with a statistical test which returns a p-value. There are no standard way to do it with the SVR : what would be the value you do a statistical test on? As for the r^2 and adjusted r^2, you can compute it easily with [these formulas](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/255/) or use the [sklearn implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html)

Comment: For your question, I admit I don't know how to answer, and that goes to the point of my question: how to actually calculate a p-value. I know that for most of regression models that I find implemented online, there is always a way to have a statistical test which returns a p-value, and I thought SVR should be the same, but as it uses a different sort of algorithm, I wasn't sure how to do it in a correct way. Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks for the links you sent, but I cannot see how the *adjusted* r^2 is calculated (and r^2 is already provided by sklearn), am I missing something?

Comment: I found in wikipedia page a straightforward way to calculate the adjusted r^2, so that at least is solved: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

Comment: I am in the same boat, and I have learned to ask SHOULD I be calculating R-squared for my SVR models, and the answer is no. The R-squared metric is misleading for nonlinear models and does not help you assess goodness-of-fit like you think it is. 

Here is a great explanation why R-squared is not for nonlinear models like SVR: https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/r-squared-invalid-nonlinear-regression/

And here is an alternative metric, the pseudo R-squared:
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-complete-guide-to-r-squared-adjusted-r-squared-and-pseudo-r-squared-4136650fc06c